# Creatures from the same kind like yours (meaning human beings)

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-request

Does the following bold term sound natural to you in the meaning of the creatures who are "from the same kind" (human being):

> - We all are human and have to help our own **fellow man**.

If not, then please let  me know, what would a native speaker use instead?

Comment: This sounds so stilted to me. Why do you need this phrase?

Comment: As suggested by [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+fellow+man%2Cour+own+fellow+man&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cour%20fellow%20man%3B%2Cc0), the word ***own*** rarely occurs in this particular expression. Personally, I think it's a bit "odd" to explicitly emphasise the fact of them being ***ours and ours alone*** like this. Since every human is obviously the fellow man of every other, my fellow man can't really be any different to *your **own** fellow man*.

Comment: @WillowRex that's a long story. :)

Comment: @A-friend keep in mind that some people will take exception to the gender-exclusive "man/men", and would prefer "person/people" even if it sounds less natural

Comment: "From the same kind like .." is not English. You want "of the same kind as ... "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **fellow man** is a useful phrase for other human beings. Just be aware that it sounds somewhat literary or formal.

I updated the phrase to sound a little more idiomatic.

> We are all human and we must help our fellow man.

Comment: Wasn't it better if we used "fellow **men**" rather than "fellow **man**" @Curtis White?

Comment: *Man* in this sense refers to human beings in general, not males, but *men* is the plural of man and refers only to males. Fellow man is an idiomatic expression which refers to humans in general, so it remains as fellow man.